# Creepers keep breaking my blocks after disabling it in 1.8.7?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In 1.8.7 I tried every one command to stop creepers from destroying the blocks but they still do. I don't know what to do to remove it. How do I disable creepers from breaking blocks?

Comment: Can you give us a run-down of what commands you've used? Also are you playing in single player?

Comment: Im sorry I got it sorry to wasted ur time I watched a guy and so I did not get it then I got it im SUPER SORRY!! to waste ur time.

Comment: That's ok :) what you can do now is answer your own question and say what you were doing wrong - that way if someone else has the same issue, this question will help them, and it won't have been a waste of time! :)

Comment: ok /gamerule mobGriefing false and then I tried it on the creeper and it worked :) thanks for comtimg and helping ;):)

Answer (score 4):

```
/gamerule mobGriefing false
```

That should solve your issue.

Comment: Do note that this will also prevent endermen from picking up blocks and villagers from harvesting and replanting crops.